# Heroku ACM Failing (HTTP challenge not returned)

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, ssl-certificate

I have a website hosted on Heroku that uses ACM for SSL certifications. This website is a small part of our entire app and I've never worked on this stuff myself. I've never used Heroku or ACM (I have read through the documentation to try to figure it out though) and I've never really done anything with SSL certifications or that side of development. So if anyone can give me any tips or point me in the right direction to fix this issue, that would be greatly appreciated!

So on the heroku website, it says that `one domain failed validation`. I have installed heroku-cli and ran `heroku domains` and made sure that the DNS target is the same. The ACM status states `CDN not returning HTTP challenge`.

Anyone have any ideas on what's causing this and how to fix it? I believe this website has been up for years with no issues so we'd like to keep it that way, thanks!